# How to deploy a chat service?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, server, cloud

I was making a thinking exercise about how could I deploy a chat service like WhatsApp or Slack (just wondering), so people could really use it. You need two main parts, the client software (e.g. the app running on the smartphones), and the server software. So how would you develop the server-side code and make it work?

The first idea that came to me was the classic hosting service, but it cannot be the simple "web hosting service", probably because something like this should be programmed at a lower level and not working with HTTP requests and responses. Maybe using specific server-side technology like Node.js (any other suggestion?) to manage different type of requests at lower level, let's say at the layer where TCP lives, would be a better solution.

So I heard about the Amazon Web Services (AWS), which is not classic hosting, it's a cloud computing service. The problem is that I don't know exactly how this works. Could I deploy a server-side application that works at that low level of networking and also makes requests to databases? Would it be difficult to offer this kinf of service using AWS?.

I would like to hear all your opinions about any aspect of this. Would you use other kinf of technology on the server? What do you think about AWS, and if you would think it's a good option, where can I get some info to learn how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

**Server Side Code**
You can create a chat service backend using NodeJS + express(or Hapi) to cater input Http Requests.

For **Hosting**: Cloud servers are pretty available these days and allow you to scale if your app grows with time.

**Database**: 
if you **already** have your DB available (cool) just use ORMs ( like ([Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/)) which provides easy interaction of Nodejs service with your DB. (I have used MySQL + Sql Server + Oracle)

If **not**, you can create a new DB (MySql- free on your hosting server (cloud?)

I used Microsoft Azure  to host a Nodejs(+ Hapi.js) Backend Service ,to be consumed by my mobile application, over the internet.
Azure gives you $200 free credit which is sufficient for you to try and make your hands dirty with them.  There are numerous tutorials available for [MS-Azure Api App](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/app-service/api/) hosting which will guide you to a successful deployment.

I have not yet explored AWS as of now, but i trust that they will be similar in their learning curves.

Comment: The thing about MS Azure sounds interesting... What would you recommend to learn about it?

Comment: If you know NodeJS  , create a small 'Hello World' REST API (backend service) . [Hello World Nodejs](https://medium.com/@adnanrahic/hello-world-app-with-node-js-and-express-c1eb7cfa8a30).   Then look for Hosting it on Azure  ( creeate a free account).  The step by step tutorials are self explanatory and are very helpful.  I did my first hosting few months back and it was just a weekend that i invested to do the above activity.